# auto run batch file containing db2 statements in windows

Tags: batch-file, db2

I want Task Scheduler in Window run DailyJob.bat daily at a certain time, this file having content like this:

```
@echo off

DB2 CONNECT TO dbName USER usrName USING password

DB2 .........
DB2 ..........
```

Moreover, Task Scheduler will run this file by cmd.exe automatically, but cmd doesn't understand DB2 command. Please  help me, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your db2 statements with the db2cmd command (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002036.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-6-35)

From CMD.exe

```
db2cmd -i -c db2 list node directory
```

There are a lot of related questions in the Web about this problem.